# App in Google Play Console is not compatible with any device

Tags: android, google-play

I'm on the way to make my app to production line but I've got a problem.
When I published App i shows that It's not compatible with any device.
In google play console it shows that my application isn't compatible. Also I can't find it on Google Play Store on my phone.

What have I done wrong? Have You had similar problem?

*Manifest.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="zzz.com.mobile">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ChANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

*gradle.app*

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
signingConfigs {
    config {
        keyAlias 'MyAndroidKey'
        keyPassword ANDROID_KEY_PASSWORD
        storeFile file('/zzz/android.jks')
        storePassword ANDROID_STORE_PASSWORD
    }
}
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "zzz.com.mobile"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 13
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    signingConfig signingConfigs.config
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
}
compileOptions {
    android.compileOptions.sourceCompatibility 1.8
    android.compileOptions.targetCompatibility 1.8
}
productFlavors {
}

lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    abortOnError false
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
//FlexBox
implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:1.0.0'
//room database
implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.0"
//---
//websocket
implementation 'org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.3.4'
implementation 'com.github.NaikSoftware:StompProtocolAndroid:1.4.4'
//---
//Fast android networking
implementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.1'
//Jackson (JSON)
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.4'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.4'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.9.5'
//---
//Keyboard visibility
implementation 'net.yslibrary.keyboardvisibilityevent:keyboardvisibilityevent:2.1.0'
//E-mail
implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.5.5'
implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.5.5'
//---
//FTP
implementation 'commons-net:commons-net:3.6'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: you set  `minSdkVersion 22`. So after 22, app is compatible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Glad you're ready to publish the application.

In your `manifest.xml` **add the code** `android:required=false` in `<uses-feature>` for *hardware.camera2* .

Rebuild your project. Upload the new APK with a different version and publish :)

Hope it helps!

Comment: It helps :) thank You. Probably it's no longer required by phones or Android higher than 5.1.